# "No such file or directory: 'hostname -I'" in subprocess

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the IP of the computer using Python and 'check_output' from 'subprocess'. My code is:

```
import subprocess

rawIp = subprocess.check_output("hostname -I")
#converts the output of rawIp to a string
ip = rawIp.decode("utf-8")
print(ip)
```

I have no clue as to why this is happening. In my code I have a few other 'check_output`'s and they all work as intended.

Comment: hostname only accepts `-fs` as arguments afaik

Comment: @DaniSpringer Option `-I` returns a list of all IP addresses for the host, see the [manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/hostname).

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy that returns my hostname, which isn't what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call) does not expect a command line, but the single arguments:

```
subprocess.check_output(["hostname", "-I"])
```

or

```
subprocess.check_output(("hostname", "-I"))
```

Otherwise, the method would search for a program with name `hostname -I` and not for the program `hostname` with argument `-I`.

Comment: Thank you so much, this works perfectly! (Also, I thought about trying this while working on it but I forgot the '[]'. Whoops.)